# If $n \in \{4k\}, k \in \mathbb{N}$ , then $(\frac{n}{2})^2 \equiv 0$ mod $n$.

Tags: divisibility

So I've noticed that if $n \in \{4k\},$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ then $(\frac{n}{2})^2 \equiv 0$ mod $n$.

**Example** $2^2 \equiv 0$ mod $4$, $4^2 \equiv 0$ mod $8$, $8^2 \equiv 0$ mod $16$, and so on...

I wanna go about proving this but I'm not entirely sure how to finish it.

*Proof*

Let $n=4k, k \in \mathbb{N}$. We want to show that $(\frac{n}{2})^2\equiv 0$ mod $n$.

$(\frac{n}{2})^2\equiv 0$ mod $n$

$(\frac{4k}{2})^2\equiv 0$ mod $n$

$(2k)^2\equiv 0$ mod $n$

$4k^2\equiv n$ mod $n$

$4k^2\equiv 4k$ mod $n$

$k^2\equiv k$ mod $n$

---

I've been playing around with this a little bit, but don't know if I'm headed in the right direction. Any tips or hints?

---

**ANSWER:** (Thanks to @Onir)

$4k^2\equiv 0$ mod $n$

$4k^2\equiv 0$ mod $4k$

$4k*k \equiv 0$ mod $4k$

Thus, $(\frac{4k}{2})^2$ is a multiple of $4k$.

Comment: For $n=6$ you obtain $3^2=9\neq 0\;mod\;n$

Comment: is doubly even the same as being a multiple of $4$?

Comment: @Onir I have changed my post so that it makes $n$ a multiple of $4.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to prove $(\frac{4k}{2})^2$ is a multiple of $4k$.

$(\frac{4k}{2})^2 = (2k)^2 = 4k^2 = (4k)k$, so indeed it is a multiple of $4k$.